# Add a new VM on separate subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, vlan

I want to add a new 2008R2 VM to my network. This will be a separate domain controller for a separate VLAN'ed off office. This VLAN (20) is all squared away on the switches. I have an office with 3 PCs in it and a printer. The PCs are all getting their IPs from our main DHCP server atm for testing purposes (all VLAN20 IPs) and they can communicate between each other, the printer has a static IP in the correct VLAN range and all the PCs can hit it just fine.

Now, I want to add a new VM, more to the point a DC for that network so its in its own domain. I've run up a new VM but as soon as I assign it an IP in that range it will not communicate even as far as the switch it plugs into - my main L3 switch. I think my problem is that the ports on the switch that my physical Dell R710 uses for my VMs, lets call them ports 7, 8, 9 and 10, are all set as UNTAGGED and VLAN10 - as this is my main IP range for my existing 5 VMs my main netowrk uses. These same ports are TAGGED for a number of VLANs that are allowed to access those servers and they all work fine. If I set my new server to use that same range it works fine - my issues start as soon as I set the server to a manual IP in the VLAN20 range. Routing, membership, etc, is setup fine across the switches... I am pretty sure it has more to do with the fact that those ports mentioned above are in the VLAN10 UNTAGGED range which is why that server is not going out through them??

On a whim I went to the console of that server through the VM Client and went into properties of the NIC on that VM and set it in advanced to VLANID 20 with no success.

Anything I am missing or could you suggest to get this up and running as I intend?

Comment: It's worth asking here, what device is doing inter-vlan routing, the L3 switch? A router?

Comment: Dell PowerConnect 6248. All inter-vlan routing is working correctly and happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're almost to where you want to be.

Your existing VMKernel port for management, and the default "VM Network" port group, are probably already configured on your first vSwitch. Both of these are currently operating untagged and your physical switch is correctly putting this traffic onto VLAN10 because that's what the "native" vlan is set to.

All you should need to do here, is create another port group for VM's to use, and use 20 as the VLAN-ID. Then assign the NICs for each VM to this port group. You may or may not have to actually SPECIFY on your physical switch that these are now trunk ports, but I doubt it.

Don't forget to add your other pNICs to the vSwitch :), you should NOT have to do anything inside the guest here (though it is possible to do so).

Comment: As a 'temp' solution I quickly spilt one pNic off the VM Network port group and went to the physical switch port and set it to vLAN 20 and up she came and started working. I did this before I read your solution and slapped myself in the head ;) What I beleive is the 'correct' solution is to remove all teh vLAN settings form teh physical switch, trunk that group of pNics, an then set the vLAN settings on the port group in ESXi. Create a new Port Group for that server, associate the pNics I need with that Port Group and set its vLAN also in ESXi. Its working now but I will move to that setup.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stop managing the 6248 from the GUI, its VERY inconsistent, take some time to learn the CLI and things will start to make sense. It can also get confusing with the port modes, because they don't just have access mode and trunk mode, there is also "general" mode, which is like a bastard hybrid I've never fully understood.